# Retrive items using GET method from Javascript and add into AngularJS $scop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new with AngularJs and Javascript.
I use **ng-repeat** to show images in a gallery and my "photos" to use in ng-repeat, is as the following:

```
$scope.photos =  [
                {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8042/7918423710_e6dd168d7c_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 01'},
                {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8449/7918424278_4835c85e7a_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 02'},
                {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8457/7918424412_bb641455c7_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 03'},
                {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8179/7918424842_c79f7e345c_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 04'},
                {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8315/7918425138_b739f0df53_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 05'},
                {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/7918425364_fe6753aa75_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 06'}
                ];
```

I have a GET method which gives me a JSON :

```
    [
  {
    "files": [
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/acn-shelf-check-images/1.jpg",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/acn-shelf-check-images/2.jpg",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/acn-shelf-check-images/3.jpg",
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/acn-shelf-check-images/4.jpg"
    ],
    "id": 5710239819104256,
    "name": "Shelf_1"
  }
]
```

I want to add more images to "photos" by calling the GET method and I can have the list of images by usings the following code:

```
 $.getJSON("https://myappEngine.appspot.com/read/shelf/"+   5710239819104256, function(result) {
       $.each(result[0].files, function(i, file) {
                       });
        });
```

How can I add the result of GET method to "photos" list?

Comment: check out angular's `$http` object that can do **GET** request and fetch those image urls for you. The request resolves to a promise, in which you can assign the image paths to your $scope variable.

Comment: @TonyGW Looking at my code, can you help me to use the $http ? The problem is that I can retrive the url of image using JS but i don't know how to add them into $scop!

Comment: @Groben I have tried : $scope.photos.push(file)  which it doesn't work! any help ?

Comment: but why do you use jquery ?

Comment: @Groben I am new with FE using Angular, JS and jquery, so I am very confused!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the values which I receive from GET method in the scope list that I wanted with the following code:

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        // Set of Photos
         $http.get("https://myApp.appspot.com/read/shelf/" +5710239819104256)
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log('response:', response);
              var resData = response.data[0].files;
              console.log('resData:', resData);

              angular.forEach(resData, function(value) {
                $scope.photos.push({
                  src: value,
                  desc: "Dummy description"
                });
              });

          });
    $scope.photos =  [];
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$http.get("https://myappEngine.appspot.com/read/shelf/5710239819104256")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response:', response);
        $scope.imageUrls = response.result; // an array?

    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how should I add the result into $scope.photos as I have explained in my post?

Comment: could you give me a portion of your salary? LOL, stackoverflow is not used for spoon feeding anyway.